# python3 gnu redline minus-sign handling

Tags: python-3.x, gnu, libreadline

I am writing a custom gnu readline completer and I found a strange quirk in handling the minus sign.

If my input is 'har' then the completer is called with the text 'har', however if my input is 'hard-r' the completer is called with text 'r'.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use set_completer_delims() to modify word delimiters.